# Input with select remains empty during automated testing

Tags: java, selenium, input, drop-down-menu, html-select

In my Java/Selenium framework I try to fill in an e-mail address. With manual testing I click the field and a pull down menu is openend. This list is filtered with the values I enter. However with automated testing, this list remains empty.

```
<div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-multiselect-clearable k-state-hover" unselectable="on" title="" style="">
  <div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
    <ul role="listbox" unselectable="on" class="k-reset" id="create-task-users-list_taglist"></ul>
    <input class="k-input k-readonly" style="width: 107.469px;" accesskey="" autocomplete="off" role="listbox" title="" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="create-task-users-list_taglist" aria-owns="create-task-users-list_taglist create-task-users-list_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false">
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span>
    <span class="k-icon k-i-loading k-hidden"></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 23.1px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;">Assign Users</span>
  </div>
  <select id="create-task-users-list" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Assign Users" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1001">User #1(user1@mytestapp.com)</option>
    <option value="1002">User #2(user2@mytestapp.com)</option>
    <option value="1003">User #3(user3@mytestapp.com)</option>
    <option value="1004">User #4(user4@mytestapp.com)</option>
    <option value="1005">User #5(user5@mytestapp.com)</option>
    <option value="1006">User #6(user6@mytestapp.com)</option>
    <option value="1007">User #7(user7@mytestapp.com)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I perform the same actions with Selenium, but the list is empty. The following statements are used.

```
//input element
element.click();
element.sendKeys("user2@mytestapp.com");

//Filtered pull down menu
Select select = new Select(element);
select.selectByVisibleText(testElement.getValue());
```

Another problem is that this website I am using in my test is developed by a third party and I have no influence here. It is used to support my Website under test.

Why is this happening? Why is the list available during manual testing, but not automated? Is there anything I have to change? Is this in the browser startup?

@Edit:
Clearing the browser cache (Chrome) did not help.

Comment: It's not clear from your code, which "element" is being operated on in the html above.  please include how element is defined.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean exactly. The input element is clicked on, the select element is shown with its values.

Comment: per your answer, it is irrelevant now, but to clarify, your code has a WebElement variable named "element", but looking at the HTML you provided, that WebElement could be pointing to the "input" element or the "select" element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I see what you mean. Next time I will be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was a bug in the application. The reason that values are shown when testing manual, was that the values were available in the cache. By deleting the cache, including storage removal, the same issue occurs as when testing automated.

It has been reported to the third party and will be solved shortly.